# Can I pass a nav_msgs/Path message directly to local planner?

Tags: ros, navigation, nav-core, move-base, baseglobalplanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Within the move_base, the nav_msgs/Path is passed internally from the global planner to the local planner.

If I generate a path message with an external node, how can I pass it to the local planner within move_base? Should I always write a plugin that adheres to global planner interface? Is there a way to pass it as a "standard" ros message?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28621/can-i-pass-a-nav_msgs/path-message-directly-to-local-planner?/) by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4402 on 2012-02-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use all of the functionality of `move_base`, you're going to have to write your own global planner plugin. `base_local_planner` does not subscribe to a path, so you cannot publish it over a topic. In fact, `base_local_planner` has no external access at all. It can only be accessed by using `move_base` and interface methods, and `move_base` provides no methods for externally setting the plan.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3